# UIButton inside subclassed UITableViewCell needs to call method of parent

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

Apologies if there answer is already out there, but I could not find it.

I have the following set-up: MainViewController which has a big UITableView and CustomTableViewCell which is subclass of UITableViewCell. Each instance of CustomTableViewCell has a UIButton added to its content view (all done programmatically).

When the button is pressed in a given cell, I would like for it to call the buttonPressed: method in MainViewController and, even better, tell me the indexPath.section for the cell containing the pressed button.

CustomTableViewCell has no nib file, all done programmatically. In CustomTableViewCell.h I declare:

```
    UIButton *mybutton;
```

Though I do not retain (no @property, @synthesize) it. The init method for CustomTableViewCell.m reads like this:

```
    myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton release];
```

but I want to call instead the "buttonPressed:" method that lives in the parent view. Been hacking away at this for a few hours, so I'd be grateful if someone could spare me my own stupidity. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Then you go with the delegate pattern !

Define a protocol that your controller will respect and a delegate of type id on your cell. Don't forget to assign that delegate for every cell you create with your controller.

Protocol :

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(void)customCell:(MyCustomCell*)cell buttonClicked:(id)button;
@end
```

Property in your cell interface :

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell ...
...
   id<MyProtocol> _delegate;
...
   @property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
...
@end
```

Synthesize your property with :

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

Implement the delagate in your controller :

```
@interface MyCustomContoller : UIViewController<MyProtocol>
```

Set the delegate when you create your cells (from your controller)

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Then from the method called in your cell when the button is clicked :

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
[self.delegate customCell:self buttonClicked:sender];
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it.  One more thing: you can call `-[UITableView indexPathForCell:]` to get the index path for the cell from your view controller's customCell:buttonClicked: method.

Comment: This is great. The only glitch is I keep getting an error that I do not understand. The error is at the beginning of the CustomCell.h file:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ResetStatsDelegate
- (void)resetStatsFor:(CustomCell *)cell;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

The error reads: expected ')' before 'CustomCell'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes that because you define your protocol before your interface then at the time the precompiler reads the protocol definition, it does not know about CustomCell.  Define your protocol after the interface and add @protocol ResetStatsDelegate; before the interface

Comment: Finally, someone has shown a great reason to create your own protocols.  Many thanks.

Comment: Stupid question: how is this better than having the View Controller simply pass self to a property in the TVCCell and calling the method in that, since it is a reference to the instantiated TVC?

Comment: Working great thanks..How simple to working with UITableViewCell.