# How to get UITableViewCell indexPath from the Cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

How do I, from a cell, get its `indexPath` in a `UITableView`?

I've searched around stack overflow and google, but all the information is on the other way around. Is there some way to access the `superView`/`UITableView` and then search for the cell?

More information about the context: there are two classes that I have, one is called `Cue` and one is called `CueTableCell` (which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`) `CueTableCell` is the visual representation of `Cue` (both classes have pointers to each other). `Cue` objects are in a linked list and when the user performs a certain command, the visual representation (the `CueTableCell`) of the next `Cue` needs to be selected. So the `Cue` class calls the `select` method on the next `Cue` in the list, which retrieves the `UITableView` from the `cell` and calls its `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`, for which it needs the `indexPath` of the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Just like your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711645/how-to-get-uitableview-from-uitableviewcell) on getting the `UITableView` from a cell - why? This seems like a code smell of a bad design decision - there are not many legitimate use cases for a cell to know either it's indexPath or whether it is on the screen or not.

Comment: I agree with Paul.s's comment. You should indicate why you want to do this, because what you're trying to do is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Paul.s I posted the design of my program in the question. It may be bad programming practice, in which case if you could suggest an alternative, that would be very helpful. I'm very new to cocoa and relatively new to programming in general.

Comment: It's worth noting that **indexPathsForVisibleRows** exists - this is critical when you want to know "where you are" in a scroll.

Answer (score 143):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

It helps reading the [UITableView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview), even if this is by some regarded to be controversial (see comments below).

The cell has no business knowing what its index path is. The **controller** should contain any code that manipulates UI elements based on the data model or that modifies data based on UI interactions. (See [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).)

Comment: It helps if you read the question. This is from a UITableViewCell, which does not have a tableView property (and by all accounts, should not).

Comment: @voidref It also helps thinking about the question;-). The cell has no business knowing what its index path is. So this code should be in the controller. For background on MVC, see [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Comment: Fair enough, but then your original response should have explained that.

Comment: @shim I disagree. This dimension was not evident from the beginning.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it was evident from the beginning the person needs the correct answer.

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question. There are times when a cell needs to know it's path. For example if you have implemented some form of swipe action on a subclassed cell, you might need to inform that parent view which cell is currently swiped. One way would be for a method in the parentView to loop through the tableView cells and check an iVar which had been set in the cell. A better way would be to get the cell to inform the parentView it's indexPath via a delegate method...and hence the cell needs to know it's indexPath. So Mundi, better to answer the question and then make your point.

Comment: Obviously yes MVC can be used by passing the cell back but if you pass the cell, why not pass the indexPath!

Comment: The index path is the "glue" between cells and data model, so it belongs into the controller. The long comment above is factually wrong. @wuf810 ...because the controller knows the relationship between cell and index path, the cell does not (and should not).

Comment: Here's two other links that better answer the initial question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913066/how-to-access-the-content-of-a-custom-cell-in-swift-using-button-tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510071/uibutton-inside-subclassed-uitableviewcell-needs-to-call-method-of-parent

Comment: @Mike I think these two answers are off-topic.

Comment: @Mundi Thanks for the feedback on my comment.

Comment: Chiming in on this conversation 5 years later. Technically Mundi is right, the cell should not know the index path. Unfortunately, `indexPathForCell` will return `nil` if the cell has not been displayed yet, so you *cannot* rely on that method. Example, if the cell calls the delegate method before the cell was returned from `cellForRowAt`, `indexPathForCell` will give you nil. So the cell needs to give you back the view model with which it was configured. But then, it might as well give you back and indexPath.

Answer (score 25):

Try with this from your UITableViewCell:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
```

EDIT: Seems this doesn't work on iOS 8.1.2 and further. Thanks to  Chris Prince for pointing it.

Comment: With iOS 8.1.2, the superview of a table view cell is of type UITableViewWrapperView. The superview of that is of type table view. But I think we're treading on dangerous ground here...

Comment: It all goes back to the "The cell has no business knowing what its index path is." argument. Accessing superview is almost always a hack and it's not surprising that it doesn't work after a while.

Comment: Totally right fatuhoku, it's not the matter of cell to know the index path

Answer (score 11):

1. Put a weak tableView property in cell's .h file like:

   `@property (weak,nonatomic)UITableView *tableView;`
2. Assign the property in cellForRowAtIndex method like:

   `cell.tableView = tableView;`
3. Now wherever you need the indexPath of cell:

   `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cell.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];`

Comment: This works because we are only storing a pointer to the tableView itself, however, is indexPathForCell reliable? I thought this only provides indexPath of visible cells no?

Answer (score 11):

You can try this simple tip:

on your `UITableViewCell` Class :

```
@property NSInteger myCellIndex; //or add directly your indexPath
```

and on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
...
[cell setMyCellIndex : indexPath.row]
```

now, you can retrieve your cell index anywhere

Comment: You need to remember to update this info manually after reordering or deleting cells.

Answer (score 10):

To address those who say *"this is a bad idea"*, in my case, my need for this is that I have a button on my `UITableViewCell` that, when pressed, is a segue to another view. Since this is not a selection on the cell itself, `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` does not work.

This leaves me two options:

1. **Store the object that I need to pass into the view in the table cell itself.** While this would work, it would defeat the point of me having an `NSFetchedResultsController` because I *do not* want to store all the objects in memory, especially if the table is long.
2. **Retrieve the item from the fetch controller using the index path.** Yes, it seems ugly that I have to go figure out the `NSIndexPath` by a hack, but it's ultimately less expensive than storing objects in memory.

`indexPathForCell:` is the correct method to use, but here's how I would do it (this code is assumed to be implemented in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
// uses the indexPathForCell to return the indexPath for itself
- (NSIndexPath *)getIndexPath {
    return [[self getTableView] indexPathForCell:self];
}

// retrieve the table view from self   
- (UITableView *)getTableView {
    // get the superview of this class, note the camel-case V to differentiate
    // from the class' superview property.
    UIView *superView = self.superview;

    /*
      check to see that *superView != nil* (if it is then we've walked up the
      entire chain of views without finding a UITableView object) and whether
      the superView is a UITableView.
    */
    while (superView && ![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        superView = superView.superview;
    }

    // if superView != nil, then it means we found the UITableView that contains
    // the cell.
    if (superView) {
        // cast the object and return
        return (UITableView *)superView;
    }

    // we did not find any UITableView
    return nil;
}
```

P.S. My real code does access all this from the table view, but I'm giving an example of why someone might want to do something like this in the table cell directly.

Answer (score 8):

For swift

```
let indexPath :NSIndexPath? = (self.superview.superview as! UITableView)?.indexPathForCell(self)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question actually helped me a lot.

I used `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];`

The `sender` in my case was a `UITableViewCell` and comes from the `prepareForSegue` method.

I used this because I did **not** have a `TableViewController`but i had `UITableView property outlet`

I needed to find out the title of the `Cell` and hence needed to know the indexPath of it.

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 11.0, you can use `UITableView.indexPathForRow(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?`:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center) {
    tableView.selectRow
    (at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

It gets the center point of the cell and then the tableView returns the indexPath corresponding to that point.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0 and above-**

If one needs to get the indexpath from within a custom cell-

```
if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView{
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self){
        print("Indexpath acquired.")
    }else{
        print("Indexpath could not be acquired from tableview.")
    }
}else{
    print("Superview couldn't be cast as tableview")
}
```

It's good practice is to look out for the failure cases.

Answer (score 1):

try this (it only works if the tableView has only one section and all cells has equal heights) :

```
//get current cell rectangle relative to its superview
CGRect r = [self convertRect:self.frame toView:self.superview];

//get cell index
int index = r.origin.y / r.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this from your UITableViewCell:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview.superview indexPathForCell:self];
```

Answer (score -1):

> Swift 4.x

To provide access to my cell, i did something like this:

I have an extension of the UIView:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And then.. in my cell Class:

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    func someMethod() {
        if let myViewController = self.parentViewController as? CarteleraTableViewController {
            let indexPath : IndexPath = (myViewController.tableView).indexPath(for: self)!
            print(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Thats all form me.

Best regards.